# MKMapview is only showing 50% width in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

Hi Guys I've implemented a MKMapView and it works great on iPhone 100% screen size, but in iPad its 100% height but only the leftmost 40% width, I've tried a few things to get it full width but no luck..

Looking for suggestions, recommendations on how I could fix this bug. In my story board, on the MkMapView I have all the appropriate stuff selected, i.e scale to fill,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_mapView=[MKMapVIew alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

or

```
your_mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```